# How to deploy dependencies with XPages Runtime in Bluemix

Tags: xpages, ibm-cloud

I uploaded my project to Bluemix using IBM Domino Designer, the XPages runtime started fine.  During testing, I hit the URL and I received a message

"The application /gittest.nsf requires org.openntf.xsp.debugtoolbar.library. This library cannot be found."

I use a UpdateSite on premises and this application also uses jars in the lib\ext folder on the Domino server.

How do I deploy external jars with the XPages runtime?
How do I deploy my servers updatesite?

When I build locally, I have a c:\sharedlib folder where I have Spring Boot, Hibernate, a Service jar with DAO.  In my designer, the project is configured to use the external jars.  On the server, I have these jars in the lib\ext folder.

I also use some openNTF projects in UpdateSites (like the error sampled here).

Please advise!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put all the osgi plugins in a folder named 'shared-plugins' this directory should be at the same level as the Manifest.yaml file in your project's deployments folder.
More details see the blog of Oliver Busse
http://oliverbusse.notesx.net/hp.nsf/blogpost.xsp?documentId=FD2